# Batch rename in unix: swap digits_*.* into *_digits.*

Tags: regex, unix, rename

I need to batch rename a list of files if the name matches a specific pattern, the pattern starts with 1 or more digit, followed by underscore, then alphanumeric. For example: "123_ABC123.txt" (the extension can be anything, doesn't have to be 'txt').

I figured the regex would look like this:

```
\d+_*.*
```

But I'm not sure how I can implement this in Unix, specifically, how do I express that the first part (`\d+`) should swap with the second part (`*`) with underscore in between?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this [`rename` command](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/rename):

```bash
rename -n 's/^(\d+)_(.+)(\.[^.]+)$/$2_$1$3/' [0-9]*.*

123_ABC123.txt' would be renamed to 'ABC123_123.txt'
```

Once satisfied you can remove `-n` (dry run) option.

**Explanation:**

- `^(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits at the start in capture group #1
- `_`: Match a `_`
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any characters in capture group #2
- `(\.[^.]+)$`: Match dot and extension to capture in group #3 before line end
- `$2_$1$3`: Insert `_` between capture group 2 and 1 and preserve extension in `$3`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a mac, so I'll need to get `rename` first?

Comment: Yes it is available here: http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/rename You can save it on your Mac and make it executable

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following solution in pure BASH.

This will print `mv`(rename) command once you are happy with this you can use actual code to rename files then.

```
for file in [0-9]*.*
do
   firstPart=${file%%_*}
   secondPart1=${file%.*}
   secondPart=${secondPart1#*_}
   extension=${file##*.}
   echo "File $file will be renamed to: ${secondPart}_${firstPart}.${extension}"
   echo "mv \"$file\" " "\"${secondPart}_${firstPart}.${extension}\""
done
```

output for shown file named `123_ABC123.txt` will be as follows:

```
File 123_ABC123.txt will be renamed to: ABC123_123.txt
mv "123_ABC123.txt"  "ABC123_123.txt"
```

---

---

***NOTE:*** Once you are happy with results of above code then run following code to rename files in actual:

```
for file in [0-9]*.*
do
   firstPart=${val%%_*}
   secondPart1=${val%.*}
   secondPart=${secondPart1#*_}
   extension=${val##*.}
   echo "File $file will be renamed to: ${secondPart}_${firstPart}.${extension}"
   mv "$file" "${secondPart}_${firstPart}.${extension}"
done
```